# VB.NET Putting the menu into controlbar like Firefox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, firefox, menu

The new Firefox versions do not have the regular menus anymore. 
Instead the menu can be reached by clicking the orange button which is somehow integrated into the form's controlbar. This saves some space on the client area.

I would like to do the same with VB.NET and WinForms.

Could anybody please tell me 
a) what this is called? I did not find any information on this on Google, perhaps because I just didn't find the right term. 
b) Perhaps a starting point on how to do this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I suppose they have no Microsoft Windows controlbar. They made his own. You can hide the menu from a form: `.FormBorderStyle = None`